# How do I cast the result of GetProcAddress to a function pointer without -fpermissive on mingw?

Tags: c++

When I use -fpermissive I can just write something like this:

```
void (*NtSetTimerResolution)(ULONG, bool, PULONG) = 0;

int main()
{
    NtSetTimerResolution = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtSetTimerResolution");
    ULONG pointless;
    NtSetTimerResolution(0x1388, 1, &pointless);
    return 0;
}
```

and it compiles and runs just fine with no runtime errors.
How can I re-write this code to not include fpermissive?

Comment: If you don't use `-fpermissive` what happens? If you get error messages, include them in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an explicit cast:

```
NtSetTimerResolution = reinterpret_cast <void (*)(ULONG, bool, PULONG)> (GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtSetTimerResolution"));
```

You might still be violating strict aliasing rules here, but you can use `-fno-strict-aliasing` to get round that.

---

And, inspired by @Remy's comment, this might be better still (DRY and all that):

```
NtSetTimerResolution = reinterpret_cast <decltype (NtSetTimerResolution)> (GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtSetTimerResolution"));
```

And I would recommend using `nullptr` in the initialisation, rather than `0`, just for form's sake if nothing else.

Comment: It would be little cleaner to use a `typedef`/`using`, eg: `typedef void (*LPFN_NTSTR)(ULONG, bool, PULONG); LPFN_NTSTR NtSetTimerResolution = NULL; ... NtSetTimerResolution = reinterpret_cast<LPFN_NTSTR>(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("ntdll.dll"), "NtSetTimerResolution"));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Found an even neater way, IMO, see addendum